# How do I manipulate the component groups allowed in sidekick according to different websites in my CQ5 instance?

Tags: adobe, aem

http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToDefineComponentListDynamically.html
I tried above but due to incompleteness of the article, I failed. What exactly happens when a page loads?
Which js calls which js?
How do I override 'update' function of ComponentList.js?
How do I get it called?
I tried using listeners and failed(perhapse due to first time with listener?)

Comment: Just wondering if you really require the component groups to be dynamically selected when different pages load.

In case you were wondering it is possible to do it manually, by switching over to design mode from sidekick, and editing the target cell where you want to place components (typically a parsys). This should open up a menu within the sidekick and then you can set the component groups there.

Comment: Hi bongman, I guess I already know that thing you told about design mode. Request you to answer only what has been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each client side component also gets a cell search path and eventually a CQ.wcm.Cell >assigned.
> The array of allowed components is kept in a CQ.wcm.ComponentList class of which there is an instance per page.
>
> The insert dialogs and the sidekick get the final list of component from that object.
>
> The "updatecomponentlist" listener can be registered using the normal editConfig listeners on the container component

As per the documentation sidekick reads the component list from the design path and to modify that on the client side you have to add `updatecomponentlist` event listener in the edit config of a container component.

I won't be able to tell you the internals but I can tell you to manipulate the component list in the SideKick.

1. You have to extend the [parsys component](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/components_develop.html) and for the purpose of this answer call it **myparsys**
2. Add an cq:listeners node inside the cq:editConfig node of myparsys.
3. Inside the node cq:listeners add a property **updatecomponentlistener** and its value should be the function provided here

   ```
   function MyHandler(cell, allowed, componentList) {
     // manipulate the 'allowed' array if needed
     if(allowed instanceof Array)
         allowed.push('your component group');
   }
   ```
4. In your page use the myparsys component

The only catch here is that it doesn't work if the `allowed` parameter is a string. That happens when you have single component or single group allowed in your design path for that page. So to make it work always, in your design path keep the allowed component list empty and change the allowed components in the runtime.

Also as per documentation, this is not supported properly

> Please note that "runtime" manipulations of the component list is currently not supported. >i.e. if the list of allowed components depends on client side changes, this can't be >propagated to the dialogs.

This means that in the design dialogs, the components that you have allowed in runtime will not be shown selected to the authors.

So I would suggest you to consult a proper CQ developer or ask on official CQ forums or Adobe forums whether this use case is recommended or not.

Comment: I believe the source for this information was: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToDefineComponentListDynamically.html

Comment: Also, these instructions did not work for me.  The updatecomponentlist event listener seems to register, but never gets fired.  I've opened a DayCare ticket and described my findings on the community forum: 
http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__0rtv-is_it_possibletous.html#forum__0rtv-is_it_possibletous__zanp-a_few_weekslateri

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, the missing piece was the cq:isContainer="true" property on the component definition.  This property (which isn't inherited from the resourceSuperType on components that extend parsys) was a crucial piece of information which has been left out of the documentation.  In fact, the component does not need to be a copy or extension of parsys, so long as this property is set (allows you to define this listener on a component which embeds a parsys component).